# ngClass does not switch value when using object in component

Tags: css, angular, ng-class, angular-ng-class

When I use the following code to switch the class everything works fine

```
<p [ngClass]="idPresent ? 'alert alert-success' : 'alert alert-danger'">
  Working
</p>
```

On changing the value of `IdPresent` in the component, I can see the appropriate class being applied,

but when I use an object in the component for the same purpose it only works if `idPresent` is `false`. When I set the `idPresent` to `true`, the following code does not apply the appropriate class.

```
<p [ngClass]="idValueClass">
   Not working
</p>
```

```
public idPresent = false;
 
public idValueClass = {
  "alert alert-success" : this.idPresent,
  "alert alert-danger"  : !this.idPresent
};
```

Can someone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

Update:

I am changing the value of idPresent after receiving response from REST API call

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
 this.http.get('http://localhost:8083/v1/uniqueid', {
  headers: {'Authorization':'Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=='}
 })
 .subscribe(response => {
    if(response) {
      console.log(response)
       this.serverId = response;
       this.idPresent = true;
    } else {
       this.idPresent = false;
    }
    console.log("idPresent : " + this.idPresent)
 })
```

}

After receiving response from server, I can see updated value in console.

Comment: If you're not using signal, remember **inside** subscribe function give the new value not only to this.idPresent else to `idValueClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complementary @Yong Shun, in Angular 16 and 17 we can use [signal](https://angular.io/guide/signals)

We can define:

```
  public idPresent = signal(false);

  public idValueClass = computed(() => ({
    alert: true,
    'alert-success': this.idPresent(),
    'alert-danger': !this.idPresent(),
  }));

  onClick() {
    this.idPresent.update(value => !value);
  }
```

Be carefull, the .html we need reemplace `idPresent` by `idPresent()` and `idValueClass` by `idValueClass()`

```
  <p [ngClass]="idValueClass()">
    Not working
  </p>
  Current idPresent: {{ idPresent() }}
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-peuz4m?file=src%2Fmain.ts) full stolen from the Yong Shun stackblitz.

NOTE: See that in the stackblitz I use `changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, but, when a signal is update, Angular update the entire view

Comment: I tried using signal but when making the suggested changes in html to replace idValueClass by idValueClass(), I get following error: error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type '{ alert: boolean; "alert-success": WritableSignal<boolean>; "alert-danger": boolean; }' has no call signatures.

Comment: @Bagira, check the stackblitz in my answer, you need define: `idValueClass = computed(() => ({...})`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you mentioned the issue in which the "alert" class is removed.

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description),

> Object - keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed.

This results that the last "alert" was `false` and will be removed from the class.

Modify the `idValueClass` as below:

```
public idValueClass = {
  alert: true,
  'alert-success': this.idPresent,
  'alert-danger': !this.idPresent,
};
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rvergc?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

---

**Updated**

As raised by @Eliseo, if you have a button or logic to update the `idPresent`, the `idValueClass` will not automatically reflect the latest value.

You need a trigger/change event to overwrite the `idValueClass`.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClick()">Update</button>
```

```
onClick() {
  this.idPresent = !this.idPresent;
  this.idValueClass = {
    alert: true,
    'alert-success': this.idPresent,
    'alert-danger': !this.idPresent,
  };
}
```

Or implement a getter for `idValueClass` (However it is not a good practice, Refer: [Getter and setter in templates is a bad idea](https://blog.touhidrahman.me/getter-and-setter-in-templates-is-a-bad-idea-because-fa8ffe397c7))

Comment: See that the "idValueClass" object not change when you change the "this.idPresent"

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, sharp eyes! That will be another issue as the change of `idPresent` will not update `idValueClass`. Unless you need to overwrite the `idValueClass` when `idPresent` is updated.

Comment: From Angular 16, we can also use signal. NOTE: Personally I don't like so much, but I feel that we need getting use to use

Comment: @YongShun I updated question to show how I am updating the value. Do you see anything wrong there.

Comment: Hi @Bagira, the update you mention that updating the `idPresent` doesn't reflect to `idValueClass`. As similar what I write for the updated part. As you first declare the `idValueClass` variable and initialize the value with `idPresent` as value but not reference type. This will not auto update the `idValueClass`. Either you need to overwrite/re-assign the `idValueClass` or use the signal as @Eliseo's answer.

Comment: @YongShun Once i did what you suggested it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i ever this problem before, i ever any key name class can be hidden like "success", "alert", "warning" etc with same case before. i try to make it single name class (alert-success") , not mutiple class ("alert alert-success") .

you can try this code as below =

```
enter code here

public idValueClass = {
  'alert': true,
  'alert-success': this.idPresent,
  'alert-danger': !this.idPresent,
};
```

i more suggestion condition on ngClass use tenary then get value on .ts

```
idValueClass() {
  return this.idValueClass ? 'alert alert-success' : 'alert alert-danger'
};
```